# Forge intsllation on xubuntu fail

Tags: xubuntu, java, minecraft, opengl

Hello dear linux users I have a problem to install forge modloader in minecraft I used the last recommend version for 1.7.2 and I only get some errors:

```
<code>

---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Oh - I know what I did wrong!

Time: 23.01.15 15:28
Description: Initializing game
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lnet/minecraftforge/common/Configuration;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2499)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1951)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.ProxyInjector.inject(ProxyInjector.java:43)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.FMLModContainer.constructMod(FMLModContainer.java:492)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventHandler.handleEvent(EventHandler.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventHandler.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventHandler.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:314)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:296)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:267)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:208)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:187)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventHandler.handleEvent(EventHandler.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventHandler.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventHandler.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:314)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:296)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:267)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:118)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.Loader.loadMods(Loader.java:491)
    at cpw.mods.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:204)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71384_a(Minecraft.java:467)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:815)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:134)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.minecraftforge.common.Configuration
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:180)
    ... 39 more
```

**A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:**

```
-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2499)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1951)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.ProxyInjector.inject(ProxyInjector.java:43)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.FMLModContainer.constructMod(FMLModContainer.java:492)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventHandler.handleEvent(EventHandler.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventHandler.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventHandler.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:314)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:296)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:267)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:208)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:187)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventHandler.handleEvent(EventHandler.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventHandler.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventHandler.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:314)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:296)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:267)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:118)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.Loader.loadMods(Loader.java:491)
    at cpw.mods.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:204)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71384_a(Minecraft.java:467)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:815)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:134)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.7.2
    Operating System: Linux (i386) version 3.13.0-43-generic
    Java Version: 1.7.0_72, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 136202304 bytes (129 MB) / 237936640 bytes (226 MB) up to 523501568 bytes (499 MB)
    JVM Flags: 5 total; -Xmx512M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    FML: MCP v9.03 FML v7.2.211.1121 Minecraft Forge 10.12.2.1121 4 mods loaded, 4 mods active
    mcp{9.03} [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    FML{7.2.211.1121} [Forge Mod Loader] (forge-1.7.2-10.12.2.1121.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    Forge{10.12.2.1121} [Minecraft Forge] (forge-1.7.2-10.12.2.1121.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    SmaugPetMod{1.0} [SmaugPetMod] (smaugpet.zip) Unloaded
    Launched Version: 1.7.2-Forge10.12.2.1121
    LWJGL: 2.9.0
    OpenGL: AMD Radeon HD 6570 GL version 4.3.12798 Compatibility Profile Context 13.35.1005, ATI Technologies Inc.
    Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'fml,forge'
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: []
    Current Language: English (US)
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Vec3 Pool Size: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Anisotropic Filtering: Off (1)
</code>
```

So I haven't installed any other mods and I don't know how to fix this, maybe one of you can help me?

Comment: Are you sure it's being installed correctly? Sometime it fails to  download a library but it still thinks that it's downloaded. Try running the installer again.

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/modded-client-support/1956051-forge-1-7-2-crash

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the launcher code as a `NullPointerException` has been raised.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

You should write to the developer about it or file a bug report.

https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC

Comment: i report it yes but how to fix normal mine craft works fine and whit tekkit launcher forge work also